# Dessert, countable vs uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

According to this [website](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Nouns_that_are_Count_and_Noncount/dessert_2966.htm), [image]

So is the second example equivalent to

> If you want to lose weight, you shouldn't eat so many **types** of desserts.

?

Can it be

> If you want to lose weight, you shouldn't eat so **much** dessert.

regarding as a general idea of dessert?

Comment: The countable form is more like "so many *servings* of dessert", rather than *types*. Expressing it as *so much dessert* is also ok, but to my ear it sounds like it's talking about the portion size of *one* serving of dessert.

Comment: When you add "types" you are pluralizing the phrase, so *dessert* does not need to be plural. Just "so many types of *dessert*".

Comment: This other question may be helpful : http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/93259/

Comment: @ColleenV. Please note that even in the link you have cited, the approved answer states: In this example, ice cream is not serving as countable thing, it is an uncountable *[base material out of which something countable is formed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/93262/46453)*, (Adam). The some is less than the whole, as it may be.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I see what the problem is - What is the "whole" ice cream that "some" is less than? A quart? A gallon? All of the ice cream in the world? Some doesn't mean less than the whole. It mean an undefined amount.

Comment: @ColleenV, you're absolutely correct! Context is everything. And so, in the context of a pizza versus two pizzas versus some pizza, some pizza is less than one pie. But you're right! When we are using it to mean, "Let's go have some pizza," the amount *is* ambiguous. I shall upvote your comment to keep it alive. Thanks :)!

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang While some pizza can mean less than one pie, it can also mean 1 1/2 pies. I can't think of any context where "some pizza" definitively means less than one pie. "Some" only means "more than none".

Comment: @ColleenV, OK :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I think of it and how I always show my students:

A pizza, some pizzas and some pizza:

> A pizza is one whole pizza.
>
> Some pizzas are two or more whole pizzas.
>
> Some pizza is just a slice or more of the pizza. It is however much is **less** than the whole pizza (i.e., less than eight slices).

I usually draw three pictures: one whole pizza, two whole pizzas and a slice of pizza removed (but still near) the whole pizza (don't forget to draw the slice's negative space).

This example also works for cakes, soda (a full bottle, two bottles, some leftover in a bottle), and of course, desserts :).

Good luck.

Comment: 'Some pizza' doesn't have to be less than a whole pizza. For example, "My 15 friends and I went out for some pizza." That many people would eat more than one pizza. We would typically not make pizza plural.

Comment: @ColleenV, I would agree with you, but your example sentence does not lend credence to your statement. You imply that saying more people had gone out for some pizza will affect the amount indicated by "some pizza," but this is a false assumption. If you break down your example sentence to, "I went out for some pizza," and "My friends went out for some pizza," you'll see that by the very nature of having used the uncountable, "some pizza," the amount of pizza that had been consumed had not been specified (though we may make an educated guess based on our experience with pizza in the past).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say in your comment, but your statement in your answer that "some pizza" is less than the whole pizza, is incorrect. I would not say "Let's go out for some pizzas everyone!" It is more idiomatic to say "Let's go out for some pizza everyone!" Sometimes the "some" is dropped, "Let's go out for pizza!", but it doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: @ColleenV, you're confusing idiomatic usage with countable and uncountable. By its very nature, some means "[a more limited quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Use_of_some)." In the case of pizza, cake, soda, dessert, etc., this generally means less than the whole.

Comment: @ColleenV, and what I had been saying was that you needed a different example as none of them applied to your statement.

Comment: Maybe you should include an example for each of your three statements there. "She ate some pizza." does not imply that she ate less than one pizza. It doesn't say anything about how much pizza she ate.

Comment: The Wikipedia link given in @TeacherKSHuang's link explicitly says that <some> is used as a partitive *sometimes*.  In general, use of "some" certainly doesn't imply that it's a partitive.  "Some pizza" can most definitely refer to one slice, or fifteen tons of pizza.  "Some soda" can most definitely be more than one bottle.